# Java: Is it possible to open a file for writing, but blow up if the file already exists?

Tags: java, file-io

I want to create a file for writing and get an exception if the file with the given name already exists. I'm looking for an implementation that is thread-safe, and hopefully in the Java standard library. The closest call I have found is this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/some/file/path.txt");
```

But this will truncate an existing file with the same name. Is there any method that will throw an exception or otherwise return an error, if there is a file with the same name already?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using File class and [createNewFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29).

Following solution is thread safe:

```
File file = new File("/some/file/path.txt");
if (file.createNewFile()) {
  // Succesfully created a new file
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
  try {
    // Do something with outputstream
  } finally {
    try { fos.close(); } catch (IOException exception) { }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is close enough, but Peter points out a remaining problem.

Comment: Can you clarify how this is better than just checking `file.exists()`? That seems to get at the core question - "does the file exist already" - much more directly. Neither approach is truly transactional (I cannot guarantee that only 1 thread/process can open a FileOutputStream on the same file) which is what I'm guessing we ideally want here.

Comment: OK, the answer to my question is in the Javadoc: "`createNewFile` Atomically creates a new, empty file... if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist. The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the file if it does not exist are a single operation that is atomic with respect to all other filesystem activities that might affect the file."

Answer (score 4):

This is the method you want: [File.createNewFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29)

> Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname *if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist*. The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the file if it does not exist are a single operation that is atomic with respect to all other filesystem activities that might affect the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can

- check the file exists
- if it doesn't write to a temporary
- rename the temporary file to the original
- delete the temporary file if it fails to rename.

As the third step is atomic in the OS so its thread and process safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
File f = new File("/some/file/path.txt");
if(f.exists()) 
  {
   //delete the file
  }
   else
  {
    //create and do what you want
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is another way and it also integrates easily with your code:

```
synchronized(this) {
  File f = new File("path");

  if (f.exists())
    throw new FileExistsException();
  else {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, didn't read about the thread safety, let's enclose everything in a synchronized block and you're done. Or you could use a mutex or a lock but this is a question related to concurrency in general, not to file existence.

Comment: You can't be sure about two processes without using an external lock (that can be a lock file or whatever) in a cross platform way.